# Matching a buttonid and changing its onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to select and match the following button code by the button id and replace what's in the onclick with my own URL.

```
<button type="button" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="CTRL53_11" onclick="return (PictureButton.OnClick(this, event));">My Button</button>
```

Can you help me match the  tag where the button id is CTRL53_11 and replace the onclick to something like window.location.href="custom.html"?

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$('button[buttonid="CTRL56_11"]').attr('onclick','window.location.href="custom.html"');
```

Thank you

Comment: In your code which you have tried, you are using wrong button id

Comment: $("button[buttonid='CTRL53_11']").attr("onclick", "window.location.reload('custom.html')");

Comment: `CTRL56_11` OR `CTRL53_11`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code work fine you need just to use the right `buttonid` in your selector :

```js
$('button[buttonid="CTRL53_11"]').attr('onclick', 'window.location.href="custom.html"');

console.log($('button[buttonid="CTRL53_11"]').attr('onclick'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="CTRL53_11" onclick="return (PictureButton.OnClick(this, event));">My Button</button>
```